# How to use ionic zip or dot net zip in asp classic

Tags: c#, asp-classic, ionic-zip

How can I use ionic zip or dotnet zip library in Classic ASP to extract zip file? I am very new in classic asp. So could you please elaborate step wise step. How could it will working in server as well.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1:
Install into the GAC: gacutil -i Ionic.Zip.dll

Step 2:
Register for COM use: regasm Ionic.Zip.dll

step 3:
  make instance of com object in your classic asp code
 dim zip
 set zip = CreateObject("Ionic.Zip.ZipFile")

step 4:
  now use this zip object to complete your task

Comment: How can I access this into server?

Comment: follow about three steps in your server   1. install  dll in gac, 2  register that dll as com  3) write code in asp  just and run that in  IIS as classic asp

Comment: It says a message "gacutil" is not recognised as an internal or external command.

Comment: for gacutil you can get more info here   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/install-assembly-into-gac